# Web part for contribute access

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I have created a web part to display chart on my site's default.aspx page. Now I have a user with contribute access, when he opens this page, he can see chart but on top of the chart he can see links like "Data & Appearance", "Advanced Properties" "Customize your chart". I dont want this user to all these option, just want to display the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this URL:

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/chart-web-part-hiding-data-appearance-and-advanced-properties/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) around your links.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention..custom code is not allowed.

Comment: This control isn't custom code - you can add it with SharePoint Designer. http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/Comments.aspx?ArticleId=28